# Create a new Pootle translation project and upload templates

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, pootle

Testing the old 2.5 version of [pootle](/questions/tagged/pootle) i was quickly able to upload my csv files as Templates.

Hugely impressed by the new features of [pootle](/questions/tagged/pootle) 2.7 i took 2 days to learn how to publish it on an Apache2 web server on Ubuntu 14. Now that i managed to deploy 2.7 I'm unable to upload the templates as i was able to do in 2.5...

Am I missing something? I somewhere read that it could be currently unsupported but i wish to be sure before taking action.

Comment: Due to major restructuring in the codebase, the [functionalities of translation templates has been modified](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/releases/2.7.0.html#recoverable-features). You probably want to check [how it currently works](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/features/templates.html).

Comment: After performance testing Pootle against a small ubuntu vm with external database i decided to go the "long" way and implement a simple version to fit my needs on asp.net.